# Copy a list of structs to a float array in Java

Tags: java, memory-management, struct, memcpy

In c++, if I have a struct with 3 floats:

```
 struct Vertex  
  {  
    float x;  
    float y;  
    float z;  
  }
```

If I have a list of these (`std::vector<Vertex>`) I'm able to copy them into a float[] by using memcpy like this:

```
float [] vertexBuffer = new float[m_vertices.size() * 3];  
memcpy(m_vertexBuffer, m_vertices.data(), m_vertices.size() * sizeof(Vertex));
```

Is there any equivalent way for me to do the same in Java? If I have a Java class VertexJava with floats for x,y,z, and these are all stored in an ArrayList, is there any way for me to copy all of their values into a float[] without iterating over all the items in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your collection e.g. `List<Float>` doesn't have `float` primitives, it has `Float` objects so you can't.

Perhaps you could use a `TFloatArrayList` or a `float[]` from the start avoiding the need to create Float objects in the first place.

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking I might have to do that. The problem is that I am building the floats by reading in lines from a text file, and the file doesn't define how many lines of Vertices it's going to have at the top. So I have to read each line, add it into some temporary storage, and then in the end write it out to the big float[].

Comment: If you use `TFLoatArrayList` you can use `float` without needing to know how many in advance.

Comment: I'll have to check that out. Hopefully that helps me avoid the additional copy, but I'll have to do some timing analysis to see how long it takes to convert the TFloatArrayList into a float[]. I assume it will be faster than iterating over my long ArrayList and copying them vertex by vertex.

Comment: The copy is about the same. It creating all the `Float` objects which is relatively expensive.  Of course parsing `float` from text and reading lines of text from IO is 100+x slower so I doubt it will make a difference ;)

Comment: Well, except that since it's already so slow, I don't want to make it any worse than I have to. But yeah, the relative cost is pretty small. Since I'm on Android, I might end up just doing it in native code anyway, but I wanted to try and avoid that.

Comment: I would consider speeding up the reading and parsing given that is where it spends most of its time. ;)

Comment: Yeah, for sure. We're sort of stuck with the need for the files and text though, so there's not much that can be done there. We have some files which are even in XML format, which takes forever to parse, but most of the files we have are pretty lean.

Comment: You might be interested in some of the code in this library https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Chronicle/blob/master/src/main/java/vanilla/java/chronicle/impl/AbstractExcerpt.java as it has code from reading directly to/from a direct ByteBuffer to a primitive without creating any objects. As such it can be quite a bit faster.  You might want to copy just the bits you need. ;) It has a version which uses Unsafe "pointers" directly.

Answer (score 3):

I think the java way would be to define a method in the Vertex class that will return an array of floats. Is there something about this that doesn't satisfy what you need?

```
public float[] toFloatArray() {
    float[] ret = {this.x, this.y, this.z};
    return ret;
}
```

Edit:
This accomplishes for one object. If you want to operate on many, perhaps you also have a static method like this:

```
public static float[] manyToOneArray(List<Vector> theList) {
    float[] ret = new float[theList.size() * 3];
    int i = 0;
    for (Vector v : theList) {
        ret[i++] = v.x;
        ret[i++] = v.y;
        ret[i++] = v.z;  
    } 
    return ret;
}
```

I changed this a little because I wasn't very happy with using `ArrayUtils.addAll()` so many times. I think it probably would give pretty inefficient performance. So, the answer to your question is that you don't get to manipulate memory in the same way, no. You can accomplish roughly the same thing, but not to the same level of control.

Comment: That will do it for one object, but I want the memory of all the objects in the list laid out together. So the end array should be of size 3 * NumberOfFloatsInList.

Comment: Fair enough. Added an edit off the top of my head that might provide the rest. I haven't tested it, and it might not be the most efficient. I'm still trying to decide if this is more costly than gathering all the intermediate arrays in one place first or not.

Comment: Yeah, that's basically where I'm at too. Can't do it with some fun and fast (and dangerous of course) memory copy and have to iterate over the elements in the list and copy them into the float array.

Answer (score 0):

yes. Use .toArray method of the list

Comment: Can you give an example of how you get a `float[]`?

Comment: That will give me an array of VertexJava classes. It won't copy the floats themselves into an array.

Comment: I see so you need to implement a method to extract those Float objects from each VertexJava objects and there is no direct way

Answer (score 0):

No.

The Collections have a toArray() method, but it will return an array of `VertexJava`.

There is no direct memory manipulation in Java; it is one of the Good Things(TM) of Java.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. The simplest way to have all floats (or rather all objects) stored in a List to be extracted into an array is by use of the method List.toArray().

Please, refer to [List interface JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html)